# Realm Android - How can I convert RealmResults to array of objects?

Tags: android, realm

I have an object

```
public class ArticleList extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String title;
private String subtitle;
private String image;
private String category;

}
```

What I want to do is to fetch result from Realm and them convert result to `ArticleList[]`

Fetch I do by using

```
RealmResults<ArticleList> results = realm.where(ArticleList.class).equalTo("category", "CategoryName").findAll();
```

What do I have to do next to get an array of objects ?

Comment: why not to use `RealmResults` directly? why do you need another data structure to keep the data?

Comment: You should use `RealmBaseAdapter` for listviews.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`RealmResults` has a `toArray()` method - also `toArray(T[] contents)` (note the [`RealmResults`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/) inheritance chain). You can use these as follows:

```
ArticleList[] resultArray = (ArticleList[]) results.toArray();
```

Or

```
ArticleList[] resultArray = results.toArray(new ArticleList[results.size()]);
```

Ideally, you'd want to use `RealmResults` instead. This allows you to get ["free" updates](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications) to your data, as well as all the conveniences of a `List`.

Comment: compiler complains about incompatible types :( https://s.mail.ru/oRPdhBqpwCrp/img-2016-03-05-15-14-37.png

Comment: @AlexeyK Adam S is right: use `RealmResults` instead, if you need it for `ListView`'s adapter, find out (or write) an adapter that accepts `RealmResults`, just like `android.widget.CursorAdapter` which accepts `Cursor`

Comment: I updated showing how to to use the `toArray()` method. Once again though - *this is probably a bad idea*.

Answer (score 28):

**Simplest to convert into java ArrayList:**

```
    ArrayList<People> list = new ArrayList(mRealm.where(People.class).findAll());
```

Comment: What if an element in People gets deleted in a background thread?

Comment: Then developer must delete that object in realm transaction as well at same time.

Comment: Yep, or rebuild the array in realm change listener

Comment: You can't pass this `list` across the thred

Answer (score 23):

```
List<ArticleList> unmanagedList = realm.copyFromRealm(results);
```

Will do it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to convert to an array, you should extend the abstract RealmBaseAdapter class from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters to keep your results in sync.

Realm provides these classes as an example of how to create an auto-updating list with a RecyclerView or a ListView.

Comment: @CarlSmith no it wasn't, they just removed the deprecated constructor, `RealmBaseAdapter` is still right there https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java

Comment: So sorry for my mistake, @EpicPandaForce.  I've deleted the comment.